# Retrieve a Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to retreive a VS project i opened on my computer from a usb stick.

I don't have the poject on my laptop and i lost my usb stick. I still see the project on the recent project list on VS's start page.

Comment: If you don't have the files elsewhere, then you can't. I suggest you use source control repositories; git and visual studio online are free.

Comment: Much in the same way that, if you lose your phone, you can't retrieve it from the "recent calls" list on your friend's phone.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a project from a remote disk does not make a local copy of it. You would have had to have done that manually. If you didn't make a copy, and you have lost the disk, then you are unfortunately out of luck.

The shortcut in the recent projects list is just that—a shortcut. It points to the file on the remote disk. If you clicked on it, it would try to load the solution from the disk, fail to find the disk, and present you with an error message.

This is a good reason to use source control and back up your code to multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot but if you have the compiled DLL and/or EXE files on your local machine, you can get the source code (or most of it) out of there by using a tool like Telerik JustDecompile.